# GRASS is crashing every time I am running this pyqgis script. Any suggestions?

Tags: grass-gis, pyqgis-3

I have the following script that it keeps on crashing. How can I find a solution to this issue?

```
import pandas as pd 
import processing 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

resol=0.0007

uri = 'file:///'+FolderPath.csv?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:4326&xField=longitude&yField=latitude' csv_file = QgsVectorLayer(uri, FolderPath, 'delimitedtext') QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(csv_file)

parameters_Red = {
    'input' : csv_file,
    'npoints' : 1000,
    'power' : 2,
    'column' : 'Value',
    'rcolumn' : '128:000:000',
    'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : 'Xcoord1, Xcoord2, Ycoord1,Ycoord2 [EPSG:4326]',
    'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : resol,
    'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '',
    'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '',
    'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : 1,
    'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.1,
    'error':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
    'output' : 'FolderPath/GRASS_OUTPUT1.tif'}

processing.runAndLoadResults('grass7:v.surf.idw', parameters_Red)

`
```

Comment: If you remove all the parameters and algorithm, is the layer loaded?

Comment: Yes the layer is loaded perfectly, even the code is running but it crashes stopping the script afterward.

Comment: Today GRASS GIS 7.8.3 has been released with numerous Python fixes: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/releases/tag/7.8.3 Perhaps helpful here.